# Wifi Adapter not working after upgrade

Tags: kali-linux, iwlwifi

I upgraded 2 days ago and since then there is no wifi working anymore. I can find the device itself in all those network / hardware commands, but its just saying "wifi adapter not found".

I tried all kind of things, downloading new firmware of iwlwifi, ifconfig wlan0 up, etc but i am no linux guru and my knowledge is restricted.

I used the wifi network settings script out of another one who had a similar issue, heres the pastebin, maybe someone can help me :)

Regards

https://pastebin.com/QW1ay8Z3

EDIT:
My system is kali linux

i used "apt update && apt upgrade"

The pastebin is a result file from this "info script" here out of askubuntu forum https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

It does every interesting command in bash for gathering info about iwlwifi devices and more. I am coming from Windows and only sometimes using this laptop (Lenovo T450) so my knowledge about linux is very basic , sorry if I cannot explain much more.

What I did (what also is put into that pastebin output) are:

```
 dmesg  | grep -i iw
[    6.622340] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
[    6.622359] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.622362] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    6.622691] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.813697] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    6.827677] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.828080] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    6.836754] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 10:02:b5:b0:21:42, OTP minor version: 0x0
[    6.900677] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.791015] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.877361] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.878740] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  812.473269] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
[  812.473281] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  812.473282] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[  812.473514] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[  812.539701] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[  812.553700] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  812.554151] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[  812.567560] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 10:02:b5:b0:21:42, OTP minor version: 0x0
[  812.629704] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[ 5344.941791] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
[ 5628.673889] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 5628.758126] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 5628.759807] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[74765.790321] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
[74766.257043] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[74766.349858] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[74766.351251] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[75980.130548] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
[75980.604316] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[75980.690379] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[75980.691820] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[78638.483828] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
[78638.957373] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[78639.042719] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[78639.044163] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

AND

I tried downloading older firmware from INTEL and copied to /lib/firmware/ - didn't help either

AND

```
rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

if anyone can help me, i'd really much appreciate that!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question and give us some context. You say you "upgraded 2 days ago". What did you upgrade? The operating system? Specific tools? What operating system are you using? Should we assume Linux? Which one? What is the pastebin showning? Don't expect people to click on random links on the internet with no explanation. We also need to know what you tried so we don't waste your time suggesting the same things. And what commands show the device? What do they show? What is the device? Please [edit] and add some detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So, first question: why are you using Kali? Kali is not a normal operating system, it is a professional tool for expert security professionals. If you are not already familiar with Linux, it is the worst tool to learn with. See what the Kali developers themselves have to say about it: ["Should I use Kali Linux?"](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). For example, Kali ships with networking disabled by default, and if you don't know that and don't know how to change that, then you really should use a normal OS instead.

Comment: Well, I was using this for 4 years without problems so far. Just after that update it stopped. And "Networking" means, missing DHCP etc for me. I have the issue that my adapter is not recognized anymore which was working all the time. Im using Kali for Pen testing sessions / ethical hacking stuff. Of course most of the tools i didnt need so far and i probably never will, still the issue is something else